# Black screen after renaming Xcode project in Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made the mistake of renaming my app project in Xcode and after many issues, I finally got to build the project without issues. Now the app builds and for a second I see the navigation title of the app and the screen, but after a second the whole thing turns black and I don't know how to fix it. I already cleared Xcode Cache. checked to see if the main.storyboard is located correctly and it does, but the issue persists.

Can someone help, please? I spent many hours on this project ...

[image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrXqD.png)

[gif screenshot](https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-dba164a1aa.gif)

Comment: Can you add another storyboard and set it to main, then check the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Any other suggestions? :-S @MaziarSaadatfar

Comment: Can you add a gif image for this situation? and also your storyboard first pages

Comment: I just added a picture

Comment: can you add this "after a second the whole thing turns black" image as a gif?

Comment: I just added it to the main post.

Comment: It is dark mode now. does it have do to with the result I am getting? It is always dark mode and this only happened after the renaming of the project :((

Comment: regarding your previous comment, I will check the post right now and try that. thank you

Comment: the rootviewcontroller didn't work

Comment: the last link you sent, it's not clear where I should put the line, is it in App delegate or Scene delegate. is there somewhere we can chat now? are you on discord/telegram and would you be okay with it?

Comment: did you use GitHub / Git or something like this?
then go back to your latest correct branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you may not specify the Scene Configuration in `Info.plist`.

The structure

```
- Application Scene Manifest
  - Scene Configuration
    - Application Session Role
      - Delegate Class Name
```

You can input `Delegate Class Name` with value `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate`

Hope it can be useful without a reproducible project